# Select from a list based on another list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists. I want to select items from list2 based on the index in listed in list1. So the results would be 22260, 3640, 5920. I'm not sure what are some of the more efficient ways of doing this. Thanks!

```
list1=[2, 1, 0]
list2=[[1820, 6700, 22260, 28820, 35420],[2140, 3640, 3660, 4180, 5400, 13020],[5920, 13980, 18820, 21280]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple list comprehension can help if you don't wanna use a zip -

```
[list2[i[0]][i[1]] for i in enumerate(list1)]
```

```
[22260, 3640, 5920]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use built-in `zip()` function:

```
list1=[2, 1, 0]
list2=[[1820, 6700, 22260, 28820, 35420],[2140, 3640, 3660, 4180, 5400, 13020],[5920, 13980, 18820, 21280]]

for idx, lst in zip(list1, list2):
    print(lst[idx])
```

Prints:

```
22260
3640
5920
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [a[i] for i, a in zip(list1, list2)]
[22260, 3640, 5920]
```

or

```
>>> [*map(list.__getitem__, list2, list1)]
[22260, 3640, 5920]
```